# Modifying and running function within a for loop Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, for-loop

I am trying to run 3 different functions that has the form {}.result(). How can I use the getarr or another function so that the all 3 functions are ran within the for loop.

```
values = ["RSI", "MACD","ROCR"]
for k in values: 
   result= getattr(k).result()
```

Runs:

```
RSI.result()
MACD.result()
ROCR.result()
```

Comment: My gut tells me that this is a scope issue, but it's hard to tell without more reference to what this line is doing: result= getattr(client, k).result()

Comment: Sorry the client part was an error. Hopefully this clears some of confusion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than putting the names of the objects in a list, why don't you put the actual object in a list (actually a tuple here)?

```py
for i in (RSI, MACD, ROCR):
    print(i.result())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Values:
    RSI = 1
    MACD = 2
    ROCR = 3

values = Values()
names = ["RSI","MACD","ROCR"]

for i in names:
    print(getattr(values, i))
```

OUTPUT: `1 2 3`

You will not be able to call getattr on your list as getattr gets a named attribute from your object which is equivalentof values.RSI of the code definition above. Otherwise you will get `TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string`

Comment: Hi I got a question related to the `getarr` function here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67897538/using-getarr-to-run-functions-in-python if you could take a look at it I would appreciate it.